# What is annotation:(id)annotation in openURL method?

Tags: ios, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

In the app delegate, there is this method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
```

I am wondering what the "annotation" is? Also, how would I use it/view it to see what it contains?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> annotation: 
>   A property-list object supplied by the source application to communicate information to the receiving application.

It is what the application that triggered the url opening wants to share with you.

[UIApplicationDelegate apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Right, I saw that, but I don't understand what sort of things would be in the property-list. And how would I view the data within a type (id)?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html

Comment: You really don't have much of an idea of what will be in it because it depends on who is sending it. I imagine that most will be empty, but it will probably have a value when a developer is trying to launch their app with a specific target action.

Comment: For example, you could have a property list that specifies a sequence of views or messages to load inside your app or make it so the url could perform a specific action when you open it. Say you have a file browsing app and clicking on a link could make you launch the app and go directly to an "add file source" page or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is a dictionary. I have only found it useful for determining the referrer when opening deeplinks from mobile Safari:

[image]